# PostgreSQL 9.6 understanding wal files

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, wal

I am trying to understand the behaviour of wal files. The wal related settings of the database are as follows:

```
"min_wal_size"  "2GB"   
"max_wal_size"  "20GB"
"wal_segment_size"  "16MB"
"wal_keep_segments" "0"
"checkpoint_completion_target"  "0.8"
"checkpoint_timeout"    "15min"
```

The number of wal files is always 1281 or higher:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_ls_dir('pg_xlog') WHERE pg_ls_dir ~ '^[0-9A-F]{24}';
-- count 1281
```

As I understand it this means wal files currently never fall below max_wal_size (1281 * 16 MB = 20496 MB = max_wal_size) ??

I would expect the number of wal files to decrease below maximum right after a checkpoint is reached and data is synced to disk. But this is clearly not the case. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [per the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/wal-configuration.html) (emphasis added):

> The number of WAL segment files in `pg_xlog` directory depends on `min_wal_size`, `max_wal_size` and the amount of WAL generated in previous checkpoint cycles. **When old log segment files are no longer needed, they are removed or recycled (that is, renamed to become future segments in the numbered sequence)**. If, due to a short-term peak of log output rate, `max_wal_size` is exceeded, the unneeded segment files will be removed until the system gets back under this limit. Below that limit, the system recycles enough WAL files to cover the estimated need until the next checkpoint, and removes the rest

So, as per your observation, you are probably observing the "recycle" effect -- the old WAL files are getting renamed instead of getting removed.  This saves the disk some I/O, especially on busy systems.

Bear in mind that once a particular file has been recycled, it will not be reconsidered for removal/recycle again until it has been used (i.e., the relevant LSN is reached and `checkpoint`ed).  That may take a long time if your system suddenly becomes less active.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. What does this mean for my system? Should I increase max_wal_size or reduce checkpoint_timeout? Or is this totally normal and I shouldn't do anything?

Comment: How big is your pg_xlog partition? Personally, I would leave it alone if you don’t expect more of these activity spikes on a regular basis. Postgres will not prevent WAL activity based on the config—it might give you warnings, but you shouldn’t see any interruption in service. Increasing max_wal_size could work to your detriment—as mentioned in the docs: it could increase time for crash recovery.

Comment: What if those spikes are happening regularly? I was seeing this behavior when investigating a regular drop in query performance which is probably connected to a disk i/o problem or bottleneck.

Comment: I think the answer to this is not necessarily straightforward, as there are a few additional data points needed--do you have any information that you can provide from your logs (i.e., messages saying checkpoints are happening too frequently)?  Do you have any graphs indicating that the performance dips coincide with checkpoint activity?  You could even be suffering from `shared_buffers` being set too high, causing a massive flushes of cache to disk.  Trying to diagnose all that could be beyond the scope of this SO question (though I'm willing to open up a chat here and discuss further)

Answer (score 0):

If your server is very busy and then abruptly becomes mostly idle, you can get into a situation where the log fails remain at max_wal_size for a very long time.  At the time it was deciding whether to remove or recycle the files, it was using them up quickly and so decided to recycle up to max_wal_size for *predicted future use*, rather than remove them.  Once recycled, they will never get removed until they have been used (you could argue that that is a bug), and if the server is now mostly idle it will take a very long time for them to be used and thus removed.